# UITableView returning nil when reloadData method is called upon it

Tags: swift, function, instance, reloaddata, dismiss

**Project Information:**

I have three views: 'Main, AddTask, and TaskTable' and three view controllers: 'MainVC, AddTaskVC, TaskTableVC'. 
My 'Main' view has an embedded 'UITableView' which is 'TaskTable'. 
My 'Main' view also has a button that presents a modal view which is 'AddTask'.
My 'AddTask' view has a button that dismisses itself.
My 'TaskTableVC' has an object named 'taskTable' which is the 'UITableView'

**Goal:**

I have been trying to call `reloadData` on `taskTable` when the modal view `AddTask` is dismissed. However, no matter how I tackle this I cannot call `reloadData` on the `taskTable` because it always seems to be nil after `AddTask` appears for the first time.

**Problem Research:**

The first thing I did was directly call `reloadData()` on my `taskTable` object using `completion` when the `AddTask` was dismissed :

```swift
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {           
    TaskTableVC().taskTable.refreshData()
})
```

but I quickly learned that I cannot call it directly because the `TaskTable` view was not loaded and I was creating an instance.

Next, I put print statements on my `viewDidLoad` for my three views (see Project Information). On startup, the first thing that loads is my `TaskTable` and then my `Main`. When I click a button on my `Main` my `AddTask` loads. So far so good... However, when I dismiss my `AddTask`, nothing loads. I thought my `TaskTable` and `Main` would get loaded but that was not the case. So I tried calling a function `refreshData()` that was part of `MainVC` on `completion` of `dismiss` in `AddTaskVC` The function would load the `TaskTable` view using `loadViewIfNeeded`:

```swift
func refreshData() {
     TaskTableVC().loadViewIfNeeded()
}
```

Then in my `TaskTableVC` under my `viewDidLoad` I have:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("table view loaded")
    self.taskTable.reloadData()
}
```

Yet the error I continue to get is: `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`
I believe this is because I called `TaskTableVC.loadViewIfNeeded()` via an instance? Whatever the case may be, I cannot get this to work for the life of me.

**TL;DR**
I need to call `reloadData` on an embedded `UITableView` when I call dismiss on a modal view.

```swift
//MainVC:
class MainVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("main view loaded")
    }

    func refreshData() {
        TaskTableVC().loadViewIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

```swift
//AddTaskVC
class AddTaskVC: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("AddTask view loaded")
    }
    //...
    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {
        //...
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {     
            MainVC().refreshData()
        })
    }
}
```

```swift
//TaskTableVC
class TaskTableVC : UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var taskTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("table view loaded")
        self.taskTable.reloadData() //error here
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Why does your `TaskTableVC` have its own UITableView outlet? It extends `UITableViewController`. That already provides a fully setup table view. Use it.

Comment: Also note that code similar to `TaskTableVC().taskTable.refreshData()` is not what you want. That is creating a brand new instance of `TaskTableVC`. You probably want to access some existing instance of the view controller.

Comment: That is the basis of my question, how would I access an existing instance of `TaskTableVC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options, for example you could use [Delegate pattern](https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef) to communicate between those ViewControllers, there are also some other options like [Observer pattern](https://medium.com/@samstone/design-patterns-in-swift-observer-pattern-51274d34f9e3) or [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift), you could also keep some reference directly to those embeded ViewControllers, but I don't recommend to do that.

Since there are segue relationships between those embeded ViewControllers  we can use `prepare(for segue` methot to assing those delegates.

```
class MainVC: UIViewController, TasksUpdateDelegate {

    weak var tasksTableDelegate: TaskTableDelegate?

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let taskTableVC = segue.destination as? TaskTableVC {
            tasksTableDelegate = taskTableVC
        } else if let addTaskVC = segue.destination as? AddTaskVC {
            addTaskVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func tasksChanged() {
        tasksTableDelegate?.reloadTasks()
    }

}
```

`TasksUpdateDelegate` informs `MainVC` about any changes in tasks.

```
protocol TasksUpdateDelegate: class {
    func tasksChanged()
}

class AddTaskVC: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: TasksUpdateDelegate?

    @IBAction func addTask(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.delegate?.tasksChanged()
        }
    }
}
```

`TasksTableDelegate` is used in MainVC to inform `TaskTableVC` that `tasksTable` should be reloaded.

```
protocol TaskTableDelegate: class {
    func reloadTasks()
}

class TaskTableVC: UITableViewController, TaskTableDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var taskTable: UITableView!

    func reloadTasks() {
        taskTable.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Comment: Also is
```swift
dismiss(animated: true) { [weak self] in
            self?.delegate?.tasksChanged()
        }
``` a typo? Where is the completion gone and what is `[weak self] in`?

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I am still getting the errors above however? But it still lets me successfully build weirdly enough.

Comment: @koza which version of Swift do you use? It is just cleaner and simpler syntax of completion block. `[weak self]` is there to avoid retain cycle. https://medium.com/@vinodhswamy/strong-cycle-retain-cycle-in-swift-f452f07518b2